# if target element is visible on screen quasion

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am using wordpress, and we have there dynamic sidebar. in the sidebar we have many widgets. what am I trying to do is to show the divis (widgets) that visible on the screen (onload - after the page is load). the others widgets will be hidden(opacity 0 or something like that) but when I will scroll I want that widget(that was not visible on screen) will appear in fade effect.

I using this code that hide all my sidebar block is on `opacity=0` on load.

I need help to show always all widgets that is visible on screen and then make the fade effect on scroll to others.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
tiles = $("#sidebar1 div").fadeTo(0, 0);
});
$(window).scroll(function(d,h) {
    tiles.each(function(i) {
        a = $(this).offset().top + $(this).height();
        b = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
        if (a < b) $(this).fadeTo(500,1);
    });
});
```

the function for scrolling is working. the problem is that when the page is full load my sidebar class that hold all widgets is on opacity 0 (like display:none). what I need is when the page load it will give `opacity=1` to all widgets that visible on screen (for example 2 of 10 widgets). then when user will scroll it will show others widgets each by other with fade effect.

Comment: Can you make a JSFiddle or give a link to demonstrate the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Extract the block of code that makes these widgets visible and put it in a function. Then add a handler to both `scroll` and "DOM ready" pointing to this function.

```
// Determine show or hide
function showOrHide(){$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#sidebar1 div").each(function(i) {
    var a = $(this).offset().top + $(this).height();
    var b = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
    if (a < b) $(this).fadeTo(500,1);
  });
}

// Assign to both
$(document).ready(showOrHide);
$(window).scroll(showOrHide);
```

Now there's a performance penalty here. On scroll fire several times per second. You wouldn't want to query the DOM for these elements and run `each` on them multiple times a second. For that' I'll leave it to you to search (It's asked frequently on both SO and CodeReview)